Investigation of ferro, ferri, antiferro, para and dia magnetism using QE
Can Quantum ESPRESSO be used to investigate ferromagnetism, ferrimagnetism, antiferromagnetism, diamagnetism, and paramagnetism? If so, could you please elaborate on how these types of magnetism are analyzed using Quantum ESPRESSO, including the specific commands used for the analysis?

You can easily figure this stuff out by looking at the documentation. Also look at the examples that come with quantum espresso e.g. in the PW/examples directory.

Oh, I also recommend the abinit examples! The input files etc. are different, but the concepts are the same and there are good general explanations. https://docs.abinit.org/tutorial/spin/
